# Mongoose find in any field

Tags: mongoose, find

I have a value that I want to find that could be in any field or subdocument field of a given document.

I cannot seem to find anything about doing this with Mongoose, not even that it is not possible. Something like this:

```
ThisCollection.find({*: {$regex: /Tim/, $options: 'i'}}, function(err, doc){
    //Stuff
});
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: @BrianShamblen That should be an answer, because that's exactly what I was looking for.